# Convergence of ratio of Bernoulli samples.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli(p) random varibales $X_1, \dots, X_n$. I'm interested in the rate of convergence of
$$
\frac{1-\overline{X}}{\overline{X}}\to \frac{1-p}{p}.
$$
This ratio should converge in probability, but at which rate? It converges point wise almost surely by the Law of Large Numbers as long as $p>0$. Are there known results for ratios of this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r(t) = \dfrac{1-t}{t} = \dfrac{1}{t}-1$ is a decreasing function of $t$ for $t > 0$, with $$r(p+s) = \frac{1-p}{p} - \frac{s}{p^2} + O(s^2)$$
Basically any result telling you about convergence of $\overline{X}$ to $p$ (Law of Large Numbers, Central Limit Theorem, Law of the Iterated Logarithm, large deviations theory, ...) translates to a statement about convergence of $r(\overline{X})$ to $r(p)$.

Comment: This helps me a lot. I didn't know quite how to view the transformation. Thank you for your response.